# How to get a particular view controller from the stack of viewcontrollers in the navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i am having a table view.when pressing a button on the cell i have to go to another view controller(ie:testviewcontroller) showing what i selected in the previous one.then when pressing one button i need to go to another view controller showing the remaing values.if he select one there then i need to repeat the above process.The problem is from here also i am carrying some values to that testviewcontroller.if i pop back to my view controller how can i carry the new values.currently i am doing like this.

```
TestViewController *test  =[[ TestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];


test.itemselected=head;

test.itemid=productid;
//NSLog(@"%@",del.navigationController);

[del.navigationController pushViewController:test animated:YES];
```

but i know

```
NSArray *array = [del.navigationController viewControllers];
```

`[array objectAtIndex:3]`is my desired view controller.

can anybody know how can i avoid this pushing of same view controller again?

Comment: I am having hard time understanding your question. Mainly due to your sentence structures.

Comment: @Cyprian main thing is i wish to pop to my viewcontroller in the stack with a set of values..got it?

Comment: @Cyprian instead of creating new instance how can i pop to my view controller with some values

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
for (UIViewController*vc in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) {
if ([vc isKindOfClass: [TestViewController class]]){
vc.itemselected= head ; 
[[self navigationController] popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
  }
}
```

****EDIT****
This should be

`for (TestViewController*vc in [self.navigationController viewControllers])`

instead of

```
for (UIViewController*vc in [self.navigationController viewControllers])
```

Comment: it will be great if  u pls edit my code with your idea and put here?

Comment: if you are not new to iPhone development this is fairly simple and it is hard to understand what you are trying to say in your question.

Comment: @bugfinder I have edited the answer as far as I could understand your question.

Comment: @thanks for the code.but i am getting an error like property itemselected not found in the object of UIView controller

Comment: does TestViewController has this property..?

Comment: yes ofcourse the code i have done is working.but i know i will create some leaks.thats why i am trying to change.simply my need is now i was creating a new instance for a view controller and pushing in to it.but that view controller is already in the stack.so i need to pop to it with the values.hope it will clear

Comment: Sorry mea culpa.. it should have been TestViewController

Answer (score 0):

For your condition it is beter to pop back and reload the table with new contents..no need to push to a new instance

Use a seperate array for datasource of table

Remove the selected item from datasource array

Then push to next view when poped back reload contents

Comment: when i am poping i need to carry some values.to show there.thats the problem

Comment: then pass it via appdelegate ...u can create a shared instance anywhere in code as [uiapplication  sharedApplication]Delegate]

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse loop on view controller stack.

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {

        NSMutableArray *ViewControllerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (long i=[self.navigationController.viewControllers count]-1;i>0; i--) {


            [ViewControllerArray addObject:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i]];

            NSLog(@"%@",ViewControllerArray);
            NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);
        }

        for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {

            //Do not forget to import AnOldViewController.h
            if ([controller isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]]) {

                [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                                      animated:YES];
                break;
            }
        }



    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```